How to Install the tseries Package in R Version 3.3.0?
I'm working with R version 3.3.0, and I need to install the tseries package. However, when I try to install it using the standard install.packages("tseries") command, I encounter errors that indicate compatibility issues.
I've checked the CRAN repository, and it looks like the latest version of tseries may not be compatible with R 3.3.0. Is there a way to install an older version of the tseries package that is compatible with R 3.3.0? If so, could you please guide me through the process?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Direct installation from CRAN, which fails due to version mismatch.
Installing from source, but I get errors related to dependencies.


It's recommended to update R. Anyway: https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/cran/setup?snapshot=2024-08-04
